# Symfony embed i18n form does not want to be saved

Tags: forms, symfony1, internationalization, symfony-1.4

Here is my code. In my form configuration i write:

```
 $this->embedI18n(array('en', 'bg'));
    $this->widgetSchema->setLabel('en', 'English');
    $this->widgetSchema->setLabel('bg', 'Bulgarian');
```

In my action, I try to save this form in this way:

```
$agree=  Doctrine_Core::getTable('agreements')->findOneById('1');

    //Myuser::pd($agree);
    $this->form= new agreementsForm($agree); 
     if ($request->isMethod('post'))
         {            
           $this->form= new agreementsForm($agree);                   
           $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));              
             if ( $this->form->isValid())
             {          
               $agree=$this->form->save();             
               //$this->redirect('homepage');
             }

         }
```

In view when I click edit I see forms for these two languages and values for each language, but when I try to save the form, it doesn't want to save.

Comment: the problem is i dont have errors.  evriting i going ok bind is ok after this isValid() is ok end after save action is redirecting me , but forms values is not saved.

Comment: I encourage you to put some `var_dump();`, like before the `bind()`, one other to see if your object is saved, etc ..